# Rails capybara visiting unrelated page causes test to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, capybara

I've got got a page with some AJAX code that I'm trying to build a spec for using Capybara.  This test works:

```
context 'from the JobSpec#index page' do
  scenario 'clicks the Run now link' do
    visit job_specs_path
    within( find('tr', text: @job_spec.name) ) { click_link 'run_now' }
    visit current_path
    expect(find('tr', text: @job_spec.name)).to have_content(/(running|success)/)
  end
end
```

After clicking the link 'run_now', a job is launched and the user is redirected to the `launched_jobs_path`, which has a Datatable that uses some AJAX to pull currently running jobs.  This test passes.  However, I wanted to add to the test to check to make sure that the job wasn't already running before clicking the 'run_now' button (which would give me a false positive).  I started playing around with it, but then I noticed that even simply putting `visit launched_jobs_path` before `visit job_specs_path` would cause the test to fail with the error

```
Failure/Error: expect(find('tr', text: @job_spec.name)).to have_content(/(running|success)/)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "tr" with text "job_spec_collection-1"
```

I'm fairly certain that this is an issue with the Javascript not running at the right time, but I don't quite know how to resolve it.  Any ideas?  This is Rails 4.1 with Capybara 2.4, and Capybara-webkit 1.3.

Thanks!

**Update**

In the parent context of the spec, I do have `:js => true`

```
feature 'User runs a JobSpec now', :js => true do
  before do
    Capybara.current_driver = :webkit
    @job_spec = FactoryGirl.create(:job_spec, :with_client_spaces)
  end

  after { Capybara.use_default_driver }

  context 'from the JobSpec#index page' do
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be as simple as adding :js => true to your scenario header so that it knows to launch webkit / selenium to test the js / ajax.

```
scenario 'clicks the Run now link', :js => true do
```

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE**

Well here's one more idea.  You could try adding this to your 'rails_helper' or 'spec_helper' file to set the :js driver.

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

Do you have other :js tests that are working properly with :webkit? Have you tried using save_and_open_page to see if the element you are looking for is actually on the page and Capybara just isn't finding it?

Comment: Yes, I have other javascript tests that work.  I've been playing around with this one more this morning and I just can't seem to get much consistency.  I'll run the test once and it will work and then immediately again without any changes and it will fail.  I tried adding config.allow_concurrency = false and config.eager_loading = true, according to this page (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15089), but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Man that sounds incredibly frustrating.  Sorry I was off on a tangent about your :webkit setup.  What's strange is that it's finding it the first time when you are running click_link "run_now".  Also I was curious about the visit current_path line in there?  What does that do for you?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, pretty sure I've got something that will at least work for now.  If anyone has more elegant solutions I'd love to hear them.

I think the issue is in the complexity of what happens in the 'run_now' controller.  It adds a job to a Rufus scheduler process, which then has to start the job (supposed to start immediately).  Only after the launched job is running via Rufus does an entry in the launched_jobs table get created.

While developing, I would see the job just launched as soon as I clicked 'Run now'.  However, I'm guessing that WebKit is so fast that the job hasn't been launched by the time it gets to the launched_jobs#index page.  The extra `visit current_path` there seem to help at first because it would refresh the page, but it only worked occasionally.  Wrapping these last two steps in a synchronize block seems to work reliably (I've run it about 20 times now without any failures):

```
context 'from the JobSpec#index page' do
  scenario 'clicks the Run now link' do

    # First make sure that the job isn't already running
    visit launched_jobs_path
    expect(page).to have_no_selector('tr', text: @job_spec.name)

    # Now launch the job
    visit job_specs_path
    within( find('tr', text: @job_spec.name) ) { click_link 'run_now' }
    page.document.synchronize do
      visit current_path
      expect(find('tr', text: @job_spec.name)).to have_content(/(running|success)/)
    end

  end
end
```